# React-redux: scrolling to a list element by ref (or id)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've got a pane component which is a ul element with a dynamically generated list of li plot components. Both components are connected to redux.

I'd like to scroll the appropriate plot component into view when it is selected in another part of the app (the id of a selected component is held in state like this: `state.plots.selectedPlot`).

I'm adding `selected` as a ref to the plot `li` component if it is selected, like this:

```
ref={this.props.selectedPlot === id && this.props.selectedPlot}
```

In the ul component, I'm doing this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...
    componentDidUpdate() {
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.selected) &&
                ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.selected).scrollIntoView();
    }
```

This is not working. Any ideas on why?

Comment: I've tried this, with no luck:

` componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.selectedPlot !== prevProps.selectedPlot) {
   this.ensureSelectedPlotVisible();
  }
 }

 ensureSelectedPlotVisible() {
  const itemComponent = this.refs.selected;
  if (itemComponent) {
   let domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(itemComponent);
   domNode.scrollIntoView;
  }
 }
`

Comment: No, doesn't help.

Comment: No errors, and when I inspect the component with React developer tools, I see that it has Ref 'selected'